# (C#) FileInfo array out-of-bounds exception ... except it is not

Tags: c#, fileinfo

Code:

```
DirectoryInfo[] d2 = new DirectoryInfo[400];
d2 = moreDirect.GetDirectories();
//Declaring FileInfo array
FileInfo[] f = new FileInfo[300];
f = d2[z].GetFiles();
if (d2[z].Exists)

{  
    if (f[y] != null)
    {
     ...
     //FileInfo does it stuff and somewhere it does ++y depending on the situation blahblahblah

         if (f[y] == null) <-------- Right here is where it does it!  And y only equals 1 here.  I checked.
         {
              y = 0;
              fileTime = false;
              break;
         }
```

So, does anyone know what is going wrong?  I have racked my brain.  I have googled, I have stack overflow searched.  It has to be something silly.  I have no idea.

Comment: I am sorry about the bad formatting! StackOverflow seems to be broken and not let me edit in new code even though I indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: Gosh darn.  I need a cupcake to relieve the stress.  Be back in like 5 minutes.

Comment: If you want to ask about problems with your OpenId, you should either email the SO team directly (team@stackoverflow.com) or post the problem on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. I will edit this question to remove this part of the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GetFiles() returns a new array. It doesn't matter that you declared f to be an array of size 300 just before, when GetFiles returns it reassigns f with the new array and the old size 300 one is lost.

```
FileInfo[] f = new FileInfo[300];  //<-- Creates a array of size 300.
f = d2[z].GetFiles();              //<-- replaces f with a new array. This array will contain just enough space for the number of files found.
```

You actually don't need to create the array at all, you can just do this.

```
FileIndo[] f = d2[z].GetFiles();
```

When you need to access it you should check the arrays length first or use a for/foreach loop to iterate over each item in the array.

Answer (score 6):

```
FileInfo[] f = new FileInfo[300];
f = d2[z].GetFiles();
```

You are reassigning another array to your `f` variable. Having just one element in the array returned by `d2[z].GetFiles();`, may cause your problem (y == 0 in the first `if` condition and y == 1 in the second).

Answer (score 2):

There must not be an element at index 1 in the array, to be safe you should iterate over the array using `foreach` or `for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)` never try to access an array element unless you have programatically confirmed it's existence.